# Ocultar un botón basado en una categoría de producto especificada Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

tengo un sistema de reembolso que agrega botones de reembolso para todos los pedidos para que los clientes puedan solicitar su reembolso, la cuestión es que tengo unos productos que no permiten reembolso y el botón aparece para dichos productos, me gustaría poder ocultar el botón para una categoría de producto específica, en la página de mi cuenta en la Vista de pedidos, el botón se compone de la siguiente clase:

```
<button class="button ywcars_button_refund">Refund</button>
```

Entiendo que para lograr esto tengo que crear una función condicional usando: `has_term()` de este código pero no puedo lograrlo:

```
function action_woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table( $order ) { 
        };
        
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 10, 1 );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi conocimiento en php es básico y no sé cómo construir la función, realmente aprecio que alguien pueda ayudarme por favor.